# Removing strings based on substrings

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove substrings from a string. These substrings are always between whitespaces and contain either `push` or `pull`.

Let's say I have the following string:

```
col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-push-4
```

How would I get the following (using PHP `preg_replace`)?

```
col-md-4 col-sm-6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?:\s*+\S*pu(?:ll|sh)\S*)+~', '', $str);
```

pattern details:

```
~                # pattern delimiter
(?:              # open a non capturing group
    \s*+         # zero or more whitespaces (possessive)
    \S*          # zero or more non-whitespaces
    pu(?:ll|sh)  # push or pull
    \S*
)+               # repeat the non capturing group (1 or more)
~
```

Note: if the string begins with "push" or "pull", this pattern may let a leading whitespace, in this case, use `rtrim` to remove it.

Depending how looks your string, this variant that unrools the loop `(?:[^p\s]+|p+(?!u(?:ll|sh)))*+` *(that replaces more explicitly `\S*`)* may be more performant:

```
(?:\s*+[^p\s]*+(?:p+(?!u(?:ll|sh))[^p\s]*)*+pu(?:ll|sh)\S*)+
```

about [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: `pu(?:ll|sh)` is this better than `push|pull`? i mean performance wise?

Comment: @vks: Theorically yes, because you don't have to parse `pu` two times in the worst case, so you have a small gain.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^ ]*(?:push|pull)[^ ]*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

or

```
\s*[^\s]*(?:push|pull)[^\s]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/7

```
$re = "/[^ ]*(?:push|pull)[^ ]*/m";
$str = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-4";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! I couldn't quite work out how to select the entire word instead of just `push` or `pull`. You used the `*` for that, right?

Comment: @CasCornelissen we selected `non space charactes then a push or pull then non space characters`.`*` makes sure `non space characters can be from `0 to as many as can`.

Comment: Right. Couldn't we use `\s` to also match other newline characters?

Comment: @CasCornelissen yes we can .`\s will match [ \n\r\t]`.Added to answer

Answer (score 1):

It also removes the spaces which exists before the sub-strings.

```
\h+\S*\b(?:push|pull)\b\S*|^\S*\b(?:push|pull)\b\S*\h+
```

Code:

```
$re = "/\\h+\\S*\\b(?:push|pull)\\b\\S*|^\\S*\\b(?:push|pull)\\b\\S*\\h+/m";
$str = "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-4\ncol-md-pull-6 foo bar";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/8)